# Xamarin IsVisible is not dynamically updated when binded to a getter property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to dynamically update an element's visibility by binding IsVisible to a getter property. However, the IsVisible does not automatically change the UI unless I refresh the page.

The following is the code snippet:

xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Picker Title="Choose..." ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemOptions}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem}"/>
    <Label Text="MyItem is Milk" IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsMilkItem}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

C#:

```
private string _myItem;
public string MyItem
{
    get => _myItem;
    set
    {
        SetValue(ref _myItem, value);
    }
}

public bool IsMilkItem
{
    get { return MyItem == "Milk"; }
}




public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

protected bool SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    bool response = false;
    if (field == null ||
        !field.Equals(value))
    {
        field = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        response = true;
    }
    return response;
}
```

The boolean property is updated in code after updating MyItem. However, the UI element  does not automatically show up until i manually re-render the page.

I will be grateful if someone has a solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you change the value of `MyItem`, it does not raise a `PropertyChanged` event for `IsMilkItem`, so the UI is never told to update

```
public string MyItem
{
    get => _myItem;
    set
    {
        SetValue(ref _myItem, value);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsMilkItem"));

    }
}
```

Comment: My function SetValue() actually raised the PropertyChanged event already

Comment: SetValue calls PropertyChanged on "MyItem".  It does NOT call PropertyChanged on "IsMilkItem" which is the property that you are having problems with

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to choose item from picker, when selecting item is Milk, you want to Label control is visible, Am I right?

If yes, I modify your code, you can take a look:

```
public partial class Page17 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyItemOptions { get; set; }
    private string _MyItem;
    public string MyItem
    {
        get { return _MyItem; }
        set
        {
            _MyItem = value;
            if(_MyItem== "Milk")
            {
                IsMilkItem = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsMilkItem = false;
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _IsMilkItem;
    public bool IsMilkItem
    {
        get { return _IsMilkItem; }
        set
        {
            _IsMilkItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsMilkItem");
        }
    }

    public Page17 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MyItemOptions = new ObservableCollection<string>()
        {
            "item 1",
            "item 2",
            "item 3",
            "Milk"
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

You can use Label **trigger** to set label isvisible, and don't need to IsMilkItem property to set Lable Isvisible.

```
<Picker x:Name="picker1" Title="Choose..." ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemOptions}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem}" />
        <Label Text="MyItem is Milk" IsVisible="False" >
            <Label.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference picker1},Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Milk">
                    <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
```

Here is the .cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyItemOptions { get; set; }
    private string _MyItem;
    public string MyItem
    {
        get { return _MyItem; }
        set
        {
            _MyItem = value;

        }
    }


    public Page17 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MyItemOptions = new ObservableCollection<string>()
        {
            "item 1",
            "item 2",
            "item 3",
            "Milk"
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @YIFAN,if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Hi Cherry, thanks for replying. This is the way I used to do it. However, I feel like there must be some other ways to do it other than writing some extra lines of code to set the boolean's value. Just like knockout.js (also uses MVVM pattern) has the Computed Observables, is there any computed observable values in Xamarin that could trigger the UI automatically?

Comment: @YIFAN, Another way is to use Trigger, please see my update.